# VideoView freeze when I call start();

Tags: android, android-videoview, freeze

I display a youtube's video (rtsp://) in one of my activities.

Here's the code :

```
        media_controller = new MediaController(this);
        media_controller.setAnchorView(this.video_view);

        Uri video = Uri.parse(url);
        this.video_view.setMediaController(media_controller);
        this.video_view.setVideoURI(video);

        this.video_view.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                video_view.start();
            }
        });
```

This code works fine on my Galaxy S (Android 2.2) but it freezes the UI on my Galaxy S3 (Android 4.1) during 5 to 10 seconds.
The freeze also appears when the user click on the widget's play button.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why there is a difference between my two phones, and why it freezes the UI in recent version, but I was able to solve the problem by replacing

```
video_view.start();
```

by

```
mp.start();
```

Hope it could help someone!

Comment: Well the `mp` variable is the Prepared MediaPlayer that the callback sends you, so you should use that.